# CCR on the 68000

Tags: assembly, 68000

So i was asked an assembly question from a friend who is also trying to learn and understand the language. He asked:

Given the following register values:

```
D0: 364B 421E
D1: F3FC 9066
```

after execution of the instruction:

```
cmp.w    D0,D1
```

what would be the resulting values in the CCR:

```
N:    Z:    V:    C:
```

and whether or not each of the following branches to  would occur:

```
BLO    <Label>     Yes or No?

BVC    <Label>     Yes or No?

BGE    <Label>     Yes or No?

BMI    <Label>     Yes or No?

BLT    <Label>     Yes or No?

BCS    <Label>     Yes or No?
```

Can someone help me out in understanding it as well that way when i explain it to him, i can deepen my understand of the concept and answer. Thank you.

Comment: wow this super seems like homework.  http://68k.hax.com/CMP

Comment: @nycynik I believe it is a worksheet for them to work on but i don't believe that it is for credit or anything, i saw "Practice Worksheet" on the page now that i recall but again not sure if it is for credit.

Comment: Start by looking at http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf

Comment: @Mark Ransom We have already taken a look at that and that is not very beginner friendly, even when asking others

Comment: The results of the branch instructions can be easily derived from table 3-19. All that remains is to determine the values of the CCR flags.

Comment: `BLO    <Label>     Yes`

`BVC    <Label>     No`

`BGE    <Label>     Yes`

`BMI    <Label>     No`

`BLT    <Label>     Yes`

`BCS    <Label>     Yes`

Comment: @Mark Ransom Okay, i think i may have gotten it, does this seem right?

Comment: I finally broke down and left an answer. It's been many years since I had to think about this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

It may help to map the concepts to modern-day terms. The C flag corresponds to unsigned arithmetic and the N and V flags correspond to signed arithmetic. The Z flag is valid for both.

The branch instructions are fully spelled out in table 3-19 of the [M68000 Programmer's Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf). Note that there are a couple of typos in the table.

For unsigned arithmetic use the following branches:

```
>   BHI
<=  BLS
>=  BCC/BHS
<   BCS/BLO
```

For signed arithmetic use the following branches:

```
>=  BGE
<   BLT
>   BGT
<=  BLE
```

And these work for both:

```
==  BEQ
!=  BNE
```

Finally there's the BVS/BVC pair. The V flag is set when there's overflow, meaning the sign bit of the result doesn't follow from the sign bits of the inputs. Subtracting a negative number from a positive number should always result in a positive number for example.

Answer (score 3):

with the ccr flags most are self explanitory except overflow and carry but, according to this http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt you should be able to figure them out

### Carry Flag

The rules for turning on the carry flag in binary/integer math are two:

1. The carry flag is set if the addition of two numbers causes a carry
   out of the most significant (leftmost) bits added.

   1111 + 0001 = 0000 (carry flag is turned on)
2. The carry (borrow) flag is also set if the subtraction of two numbers
   requires a borrow into the most significant (leftmost) bits subtracted.

   0000 - 0001 = 1111 (carry flag is turned on)

Otherwise, the carry flag is turned off (zero).
 * 0111 + 0001 = 1000 (carry flag is turned off [zero])
 * 1000 - 0001 = 0111 (carry flag is turned off [zero])

In unsigned arithmetic, watch the carry flag to detect errors.
In signed arithmetic, the carry flag tells you nothing interesting.

### Overflow Flag

The rules for turning on the overflow flag in binary/integer math are two:

1. If the sum of two numbers with the sign bits off yields a result number
   with the sign bit on, the "overflow" flag is turned on.

   0100 + 0100 = 1000 (overflow flag is turned on)
2. If the sum of two numbers with the sign bits on yields a result number
   with the sign bit off, the "overflow" flag is turned on.

   1000 + 1000 = 0000 (overflow flag is turned on)

Otherwise, the overflow flag is turned off.
 * 0100 + 0001 = 0101 (overflow flag is turned off)
 * 0110 + 1001 = 1111 (overflow flag is turned off)
 * 1000 + 0001 = 1001 (overflow flag is turned off)
 * 1100 + 1100 = 1000 (overflow flag is turned off)

Note that you only need to look at the sign bits (leftmost) of the three
numbers to decide if the overflow flag is turned on or off.

If you are doing two's complement (signed) arithmetic, overflow flag on
means the answer is wrong - you added two positive numbers and got a
negative, or you added two negative numbers and got a positive.

If you are doing unsigned arithmetic, the overflow flag means nothing
and should be ignored.

Comment: How would I check that the overflow flag was set? What Easy86k code would I write?