# 68000 assembly - Why does the 68000 ISA include both signed and unsigned branches?

Tags: 68000

I had this question on my exam yesterday and it is still puzzling me. Could someone please explain to me why the 68000 isa include both singed and unsigned branches.

Comment: I have been working with the 68k family for years, there is no such term commonly used in the 68k jargon. Do you mean *conditional/unconditional* or are you talking about *branch offsets/distances*?

Comment: Or do you mean *branch predicates*?

Answer (score 2):

The question is probably about `bhi/blo/bhs/bls` branches versus `bgt/blt/bge/ble` branches.

The former group takes into account only `C` and `Z` flags, which is useful when you compare values you treat as *unsigned*.

The latter group takes into account only `N`, `V` and `Z` flags, which allows you to compare *signed* values.

You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615568/ccr-on-the-68000) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423548/68000-assembly-language-cmpi-b).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not the *branches*, but the *comparison* that is signed or unsigned. The `cmp` instruction (and all other instructions that affect the N, V, Z, C flags) return both a result that can be interpreted as both signed and unsigned depending on wether the N and V flag (signed) or the C (unsigned) flag are considered in addition to the Z flag in the interpretation. bh[is]/bl[os] do the former, bg[te] and bl[te] do the latter.